# cygwin terminal converts my letters to numbers

Tags: c, netbeans, cygwin

I recently coded a '.C' file with scanf in order to take keyboard inputs.  To my great surprise, the cygwin terminal converted all the letters I typed to numbers. My program ran properly though.  The cygwin terminal just didn't show the correct input that I typed.  It even converted some non-alphabet keys into symbols.

If I pressed the same alphabet key multiple times, the numbers (showing up in the cygwin terminal) would change each time I pressed the key.  I talked to my computer science professor about this and he didn't know how to fix it.

Another thing to be noted is that my professor was able to use the cygwin executable(?) via the command terminal in order to run my '.C' file.  When he ran the program in this way, the command terminal was able to accept letters.

I got the cygwin installation package from the GATech mirror website and this is the first error I've come across using cygwin.

I am using windows XP and netbeans to run the '.C' ;

Comment: We need to see the code in order to figure out what the problem is. Without that, my best guess is that you have a problem on line 42.

Comment: Can you open up cygwin and do things normally? Like, type "ls -al" and navigate around, and so on?

Comment: @Michael Madsen: 42.... always the answer ;)))

Comment: @Noon Silk , no I cannot.  Any letters that I type show up as numbers in the terminal.  While the code words I printed from my code using printf show up as they are supposed to.

Comment: @everyone , this is not a coding problem.  It is a cygwin problem. My code is perfectly fine. There is just something wrong with cygwin.  I don't no if it's an installation problem or what.

Answer (score 0):

check your `.(bash)rc` settings, try alternativ "consoles" (mintty, xterm,...)

> ...was able to use the cygwin executable...

they are still windows .exe files